# Which API level to use with Support Library in Android?

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I want to create an Android app that can be used on `2.3.3` all the way through to `4.0.3`. I want to use the Support Library, so that I can use fragments, etc.

Do I set the build target to API *level 10* (2.3.3) or do I set it to *15* (4.0.3)?

Comment: from : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html as you want to run on the (2.3.3) so use API level 10 and for fragments use [compatibility-library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/12/example-of-using-compatibility-package.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers here are somewhat misleading, as you don't *need* to set your `targetSdkVersion="15"` in order for your application to be used all the way up to version 4.0.3. Setting your `minSdkVersion="10"` alone will allow you to use your application on all devices running Gingerbread and above.

The `targetSdkVersion` attribute specifies the API level on which the application is designed to run. Preferably you would want its value to correspond to the most recently released SDK (`"15"`, at the time of this posting). Strictly speaking, however, its value should be given by the largest SDK version number that you have tested your application against.

The benefits of a higher `targetSdkVersion` is that it will enable you to take advantage of shiny new features in the recently released APIs. For instance, if in this case you didn't set your `targetSdkVersion`, it would default to your `minSdkVersion` (which is currently `"10"`). Because of this, your application won't be able to make use of the new UI themes (i.e. `Theme.Holo`) introduced in `HoneyComb` and `ICS`, and will probably be forced into compatibility mode (which is ugly and makes your app look old and poorly maintained).

Comment: +1 for this being a better explanation if my answer was misleading.

Comment: "The answers here are somewhat misleading"? can you tell me what's wrong with my answer ........................?

Comment: I'm not even sure what your "answer" is... it's just a bunch of links?

Answer (score 2):

You should set your build target to 15, but minimum SDK to 10.

This way, the Support Libraries will still work on 10, but with reflection you will also be able to directly access higher API version features if you so wanted.

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> is what I've got in my manifest and I've built against 4.0.3. Realised that I needed to be able to code against 4 apis when I started building an actionbar solution.